# $f(x)=x\cdot \ln(x)$ uniformly continuous in $(0,3]$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I have to decide if the function $f(x)=x\cdot \ln(x)$  in the interval $(0,3]$ is uniformly continuous but I don't know how to start.

In general I have problems with this kind of proof. Please can someone make me understand?

Comment: Re: Your comment  regarding $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ : The derivative $f'(x)$ tends to $\infty$ as $x\to \infty.$ Suppose $r,s>0$ such that $\forall x,y\,(|x-y|< r\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<s\,).$ Take $x$ such that $\forall y> x\,(f'(y)>s/r).$ Then  for some $y\in (x,x+r)$ we have $s/r>(f(x+r)-f(x))/r=f'(y)>s/r ,$  a contradiction.  So $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend $f$ to $0$ by putting $f(0)=0$. Since $\lim_{x\to0}x\ln(x)=0$, this extension is continuous. And every continuous function whose domain is closed and bounded is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks , If I had $(0,+ \infty)$ what I would do?

Comment: That's another question. Please post it as such.